# Can I use IDEA Jetty Runner plugin with lombok?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetty, intellij-lombok-plugin

I would like to use IDEA Jetty Runner plugin with lombok, but so far I get this error:
`java: cannot find symbol. symbol: variable log`

That's because I use the lombok annotation @Slf4j for my logs, and I assume the jetty plugin does not process the annotations.

The annotation processing feature is enabled in IntelliJ.

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Slf4j // Lombok annotation for logs
@WebServlet(name = "MyServlet", value = "/my-servlet-url")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doPut(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        log.info("First Log");
    }
}
```

Using `mvn jetty:run` works perfectly.

Comment: Have you installed Lombok plugin?

Comment: Yes lombok plugin is installed

Comment: When do you get this error? While running or it's highlighted in editor?

Comment: while running the Jetty Runner plugin

Comment: Have you try to contact plugin vendor: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7505-idea-jetty-runner ?